# cordova ios plugin add/remove error

Tags: plugins, cordova, sencha-touch-2, syntax-error

Cordova -v 3.1.0-0.1.0 on OS X.

When trying to add or remove a plugin, at some point (after one or two plugins) the command fails.

```
cordova plugins rm org.apache.cordova.media

{ name: 'SyntaxError',
 message: 'Expected "/*", "=" or [A-Za-z0-9_] but "." found.',
 line: 298,
 column: 11 }
```

With debug

```
cordova -d  plugins rm org.apache.cordova.media

Calling plugman.uninstall on plugin "org.apache.cordova.media" for platform "ios"
Uninstalling org.apache.cordova.media...
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Parsing ios project files...
Parsing iOS project files...
undefined
```

I do have an 'ios' platform, but obviously there isn't an 'iOS' platform.

Comment: I am also getting errors similar to this.  It seems to only affect iOS, because android seems to build just fine.  See here (although not that helpful yet) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4994?attachmentOrder=asc
I encourage you to sign up for an apache user account so you can up vote this issue.